# Azure ServiceBus sendQueueMessage REALLY slow

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm using a simple node.js script to send a message to a service bus.  It suddenly seems to have slowed down to the point where a single operation is taking 16 seconds.

Anyone have any thoughts on that?  I can't seem to find anything on Azure that would help me understand why that't the case, so any pointers greatly appreciated.

Outline code for test script below.

```html
const azure = require('azure');
const azureConnectionString = 'Endpoint=...';
const queue = 'myqueue';
const serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService(azureConnectionString);

let customProperties = {
    "property1":"test property"
}

sendMessage(customProperties);


function sendMessage(customProperties) {
    if (customProperties) {
        let queuemessage = {};
        queuemessage.body = "body";
        queuemessage.customProperties = customProperties;
        console.time("sendMessage");
        serviceBusService.sendQueueMessage(queue, queuemessage, function (error) {
            if (!error) {
                console.timeEnd("sendMessage");
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
    } else {
        console.log('service bus request missing parameters');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the code running in Azure or on premise?

Comment: On my laptop on premise for testing. Actual code is on Azure.

Comment: Can you try setting the [ConnectivityMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.connectivitymode.aspx) to HTTPS?

Comment: I tried that using serviceBusService.ConnectivityMode = 'Https' but I'm not sure if that's right or supported based on the link you sent? Didn't seem to make a difference... Currently taking between 20-30 seconds to send now...

Comment: Yeah, that link was for .NET - I did not find the JavaScript equivalent.  The point of setting the property is to avoid probing for the TCP ports.  When I have code running on premise, ports other than 80/443 are blocked.  The probe takes about 25 seconds before falling back to HTTP.  Hence, setting the mode explicitly avoids that delay.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure if I did it right, and I don't see any entries for connectivityMode in any of the js files I looked through in the azure module, so I don't think it's supported.  I can see why that might make a difference though...

Comment: Could  you please make sure that your test environment is in the same region with your Service Bus? It could be the internet issue. Or could you please try to deploy your test script to Azure, and check the latency? Any update, please feel free to let me know.